# Why can't I post on chat?

Tags: support, chat

On any sites chat, I have over 20 on all of them, I can't post. It says I need over 20 rep on "The Stack Exchange Network". I follow the link provided, I see no rep measure. All sites (since I'm "*trusted*" on Area51) I've joined I have at least 101 rep. So why can't I post?

Comment: What is your "parent user" on chat? From what site? Look on your chat profile page.

Comment: For some reason It had my old profile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earlier this year *(before I had a grip on question asking)* I deleted my SO profile because I couldn't do anything, neither ask nor answer. It turns out that chat was linked to that old profile and not my current one. So I just changed the parent profile to a different, high rep, site.